# Sum columns if adjacent columns match if statements in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have to sum column A if adjacent column B is within a particular range. Here's what I mean:

```
Sheet 1

   A   B
1  $2  November
2  $5  November

Sheet 2
   A
1  for each B1:B where the cell = November, sum adjacent A (my result should be $7)
2
```

Is there a way to do this in Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this formula work as you want:

`=SUMIF(B:B,"November",A:A)`

Comment: Yep, this is great! Future people: I ended up having to use SUMIFS because I had multiple conditions. Interestingly enough, the Google Docs documentation doesn't include a link to SUMIFS from the SUMIF page.